# Why won't 'docker run' on a swarm show output from a command?

Tags: docker, cluster, docker-swarm

I've successfully setup a Docker Swarm cluster consisting of one master and two nodes.

Everything works as expected, only one thing deviates from the documentation. [According to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/) (look for *"Run a container on the Swarm"*) I should see the output from the command when I run something on the Swarm, but that's not what happens to me:

```
$ docker run hello-world   # <<< no output

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
663f36f72ee1        hello-world:latest   "/hello"               4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                       node-1/serene_pare
...

$ docker logs 663f36f72ee1 # <<< however everything looks good
Hello from Docker.
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Using `run -i` solves the problem. Still, I'm curious why `-i` is necessary with Swarm only, and why the documentation doesn't say so.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is wrong and [this issue](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/2033) fixes the documentation.

The reason why the -i --interactive flag is needed is because the -i flag allows us to make an interactive connection by grabbing the standard in (STDIN) of the container since the container is on another host.

Comment: The issue has been closed saying that it happens only with vagrant. Obviously I'm not using vagrant

Comment: you are correct. I experienced the issue reproducing it using vagrant and posted this comment however then closed it when I noticed it working the way it was supposed to using docker-machine (as the docs suggest)